# Is it forbidden for an unmarried Jewish man to sleep with an unmarried woman?

Tags: halacha

Assume that it’s done completely in private and nobody else is made aware.

If yes, where does it come from?

It reminds me of what Rab Ilai said (not sure, can’t remember exactly) that if one can’t resist the urge, one should dress in dark and go to another city.

Comment: Of course. Lashes

Comment: mbloch, Josh K: does not answer. The first part of the accepted answer refers to the prohibition on Jewish prostitutes. The second part cites the Rambam and then unnamed “medieval rabbis” whose opinion may restrict his opinion. Chabad’s link in a comment is a metaphorical opinion which appears to make some sense but is restricted to pre-marital intercourse with one’s bride. The accepted answer raises an interesting question: we are not kings, but there appears to exist sleeping beyond marriage.

Comment: Please edit your question to add any elements to distinguish your question from the one of which it's a duplicate